# Eclipse Having Trouble with jsp taglib

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, jsp-tags

I have an eclipse servlet web project.  It works with no issues.  I copied it in the workspace and then pasted it and changed the name in the process.  I ran it locally and it did load with no errors.  However, for some reason it does not work correctly anymore.  It looks like taglib is not working correctly in the html.  I can tell because the taglib's print out at the top of the webpage as if they are not being properly recognized and the browser just prints them out as if they were text. Here is what it looks like,

[image]

Here are the taglibs,

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sf" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s" %>
```

Like I said the non-copied version runs fine.  Here are the jars that I am using,

[image]

I had to add javax.servlet.jsp.jar to the new project.  It was not required in the original project.  I did re-set the correct build paths for all of the jars.  Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Try recopying in some text editor first and check for any special characters which might have crept in the code!

Comment: Thank you Shavam but I don't think that is the problem.  I can build the code and run it outside of eclipse locally or on and AWS instance.  In windows command prompt: gradle build, cd build\libs, java -jar myjavaprogram.war.  It runs the exact same code perfectly outside of eclipse.  There is something wrong in the eclipse setup that causes it not to run.  I see a lot of people have exactly the same problem.  It is associated with the fact that eclipse does not exactly execute the same environment.  I just have not found what I am doing wrong just yet.